# Memory leak converting CVPixelBuffer to UIImage

Tags: swift, memory, cvpixelbuffer

These days I am encountering a problem in relation to memory usage in my app that rarely causes this one to crash. I noticed from the memory inspector that it is caused by converting the CVPixelBuffer (of my camera) to UIimage. Below you can see the code I use:

```
extension UIImage {

  public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    var cgImage: CGImage?
    
    VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &cgImage)
    
    guard let cgImage = cgImage else {
      return nil
    }
    
    self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.